# head and tail doesn't take negative number as argument for data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Why `head` and `tail` work differently for `data.table`? Is it by design?

```
> head(data.frame(x=1:10), -2)
  x
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
> head(data.table(x=1:10), -2)
Error in seq_len(min(n, nrow(x))) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
> tail(data.table(x=1:10), -2)
    x
1: NA
2: NA
3: NA
4: 10
> tail(data.frame(x=1:10), -2)
    x
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10 10
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, this was reported before, [#2375](http://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=975&aid=2375&group_id=240). This is now fixed in [v1.8.11](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=240). From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable):**

> `head()` and `tail()` handle negative 'n' values correctly now, #2375. Thanks to Garrett See for reporting. Also it results in an error when `length(n) != 1`. Tests added.