# Efficiently selecting top number of rows for each unique value of a column in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to take a subset of a data frame, based on the occurence of a value. This is best explained in an example, given below. This question has a high relation to: [Selecting top finite number of rows for each unique value of a column in a data fame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191236/selecting-top-finite-number-of-rows-for-each-unique-value-of-a-column-in-a-data)
However, i want to vary the number of items selected by the head() command.

```
#Sample data
input <- matrix( c(1000001,1000001,1000001,1000001,1000001,1000001,1000002,1000002,1000002,1000003,1000003,1000003,100001,100002,100003,100004,100005,100006,100002,100003,100007,100002,100003,100008,"2011-01-01","2011-01-02","2011-01-01","2011-01-04","2011-01-01","2011-01-02","2011-01-01","2011-01-04","2011-01-01","2011-01-02","2011-01-01","2011-01-04"), ncol=3)
colnames(input) <- c( "Product" , "Something" ,"Date")
input <- as.data.frame(input)
input$Date <- as.Date(input[,"Date"], "%Y-%m-%d")

#Sort based on date, I want to leave out the entries with the oldest dates.
input <- input[ with( input, order(Date)), ]

#Create number of items I want to select
table_input <- as.data.frame(table(input$Product))
table_input$twentyfive <- ceiling( table_input$Freq*0.25  )

#This next part is a very time consuming method (Have 2 mln rows, 90k different products)

first <- TRUE

for( i in table_input$Var1 ) {
  data_selected <- input[input$Product == i,]
  number <- table_input[table_input$Var1 == i ,]$twentyfive

  head <- head( data_selected, number)        

  if( first == FALSE) {
    output <- rbind(output, head)
  } else {
    output <- head
  }
  first <- FALSE
}
```

Hoping that someone knows a better, more efficient way. I tried to use the split function from the answer here: [Selecting top finite number of rows for each unique value of a column in a data fame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191236/selecting-top-finite-number-of-rows-for-each-unique-value-of-a-column-in-a-data) to split on the products and then try to iterate over them and select the head(). However the split function always runs out of memory (cannot allocate ..)

```
input_split <- split(input, input$Product) #Works here, but not i my problem.
```

So in the end my problem is that i want te select a different amount of each unique Product. So here 2 items from 1000001 and 1 item from 1000002 and 1000003.

Comment: The lack of answers is probably because you have a overly complicated script up there. Try to reduce the problem down to the bare essentials so it is easy, easy, easy to read and I think you will get an answer quicker.

Comment: @SimonO101 Thnx, i will remove some of the script then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two solutions spring to mind. `plyr::ddply` is designed for your needs but using a `data.table` will be waaaaaay faster.

You want to take a `data.frame` split it up into chunks, remove all the bottom 25% of rows of each chunk which is sorted by date and recombine into a `data.frame`. This can be accomplished in one simple line...

```
require( plyr )
ddply( input , .(Product) , function(x) x[ - c( 1 : ceiling( nrow(x) * 0.25 ) ) , ] )
#  Product Something       Date
#1 1000001    100005 2011-01-01
#2 1000001    100002 2011-01-02
#3 1000001    100006 2011-01-02
#4 1000001    100004 2011-01-04
#5 1000002    100007 2011-01-01
#6 1000002    100003 2011-01-04
#7 1000003    100002 2011-01-02
#8 1000003    100008 2011-01-04
```

#### **`data.table`** solution

For `data.table` you will need the latest development version from `r-forge` (due to us of negative subscript [not being implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18922365/1478381) in the CRAN version of data.table yet). Make sure you follow the `install.package` call to get the latest version...

```
install.packages( "data.table" , repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org" )
require( data.table )
DT <- data.table( input )

#  Sort by Product then Date very quickly
setkeyv( DT , c( "Product" , "Date" ) )

#  Return the bottom 75% of rows (i.e. not the earliest)
DT[ ,  tail( .SD , -ceiling( nrow(.SD) * .25 ) )  , by = Product ] 
#   Product Something       Date
#1: 1000001    100005 2011-01-01
#2: 1000001    100002 2011-01-02
#3: 1000001    100006 2011-01-02
#4: 1000001    100004 2011-01-04
#5: 1000002    100007 2011-01-01
#6: 1000002    100003 2011-01-04
#7: 1000003    100002 2011-01-02
#8: 1000003    100008 2011-01-04
```

#### A better way to use `data.table`

You could more easily do this (so you don't require development version of `data.table`)...

```
DT[ ,  .SD[ -c( 1:ceiling( .25 * .N ) ) ] , by = Product ]
```

And you can also use `lapply` in the `j` argument (I was worried about my use of `.SD`) and this runs in ~ 14 seconds on a `data.table` of 2e6 rows with 90,000 products (groups)...

```
set.seed(1)
Product <- sample( 1:9e5 , 2e6 , repl = TRUE )
dates <- sample( 1:20 , 2e6 , repl = TRUE )
Date <- as.Date( Sys.Date() + dates )
DT <- data.table( Product = Product , Date = Date )

system.time( { setkeyv( DT , c( "Product" , "Date" ) ); DT[ , lapply( .SD , `[` ,  -c( 1:ceiling( .25 * .N ) ) ) , by = Product ] } )
#   user  system elapsed 
#  14.65    0.03   14.74
```

#### Update: The *best* way to use `data.table`!

So thanks to **@Arun** (who is now an author of the `data.table` package) we now have the best way to use `data.table` which is to use `.I` which is an integer vector of all the row indices, subset in `[` by removing the first 25% of record with `-(1:ceiling(.N*.25))`, and then performaing a subset using these row indices to get the final table. This is ~ 4-5 times faster than using my `.SD` method above. Amazing stuff!

```
system.time( DT[ DT[, .I[-(1:ceiling(.N*.25))] , by = Product]$V1] )
   user  system elapsed 
   3.02    0.00    3.03
```

Comment: ddply( input , .(Product) , function(x){    head(x, table_input[table_input$Var1 == x$Product[1],]$twentyfive )  } )  This seems to do the same as my whole for loop.. Thnx @Simon. Would you happen to know how I can compare the performance?

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I use stackoverflow alot to search for solutions, but you realy took it to a next level. Computing time you saved me with your data.table solution: appro. 720 mins with my (improved, not the one above) for-loop to 10 mins with data.table.

Comment: @Freddy I get it running in 14 seconds on a 2e6 row data.table with 90,000 products to group by.

Comment: @SimonO101, `nrow(.SD) = .N`. Also, you can replace `.SD` with `.I`. Using `.SD` would be time-consuming here. That is, `DT[DT[, .I[-(1:ceiling(.N*.25))], by=Product]$V1]` will be much faster. The key will be same as that of `DT` using this method. You can change that if you want.

Comment: @Arun thanks for this great suggestion. I hope I have more or less explained it ok in the answer? Thanks!

Comment: @Arun Awesome, I should get to know data.table better, this works so well on large data sets. Subsetting 3 data sets (for 25,50 and 75) takes me 4 seconds now. Which makes it 10000 times faster then my initial 'solution'.

Comment: @SimonO101, no problem. Made a minor change. Hope it is okay.

Comment: @Freddy, glad! get started with the introduction vignette and then probably the FAQ. Ask if you have doubts, here or on data.table mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using `mapply` and your `input` and `table_input`:

```
    #your code
    #input <- matrix( c(1000001,1000001,1000001,1000001,1000001,1000001,1000002,1000002,1000002,1000003,1000003,1000003,100001,100002,100003,100004,100005,100006,100002,100003,100007,100002,100003,100008,"2011-01-01","2011-01-02","2011-01-01","2011-01-04","2011-01-01","2011-01-02","2011-01-01","2011-01-04","2011-01-01","2011-01-02","2011-01-01","2011-01-04"), ncol=3)
    #colnames(input) <- c( "Product" , "Something" ,"Date")
    #input <- as.data.frame(input)
    #input$Date <- as.Date(input[,"Date"], "%Y-%m-%d")

    #Sort based on date, I want to leave out the entries with the oldest dates.
    #input <- input[ with( input, order(Date)), ]

    #Create number of items I want to select
    #table_input <- as.data.frame(table(input$Product))
    #table_input$twentyfive <- ceiling( table_input$Freq*0.25  )

    #function to "mapply" on "table_input"
    fun = function(p, d) { grep(p, input$Product)[1:d] }

    #subset "input"
    input[unlist(mapply(fun, table_input$Var1, table_input$twentyfive)),]

       Product Something       Date
    1  1000001    100001 2011-01-01
    3  1000001    100003 2011-01-01
    7  1000002    100002 2011-01-01
    11 1000003    100003 2011-01-01
```

I, also, called `system.time` and `replicate` to compare speed of `mapply` and the alternatives from SimonO101's answer:

```
    #SimonO101's code
    #require( plyr )
    #ddply( input , .(Product) , function(x) x[ - c( 1 : ceiling( nrow(x) * 0.25 ) ) , ] )
    #install.packages( "data.table" , repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org" )
    #require( data.table )
    #DT <- data.table( input )
    #setkeyv( DT , c( "Product" , "Date" ) )
    #DT[ ,  tail( .SD , -ceiling( nrow(.SD) * .25 ) )  , by = Product ]

    > system.time(replicate(10000, input[unlist(mapply(fun, table_input$Var1, table_input$twentyfive)),]))
       user  system elapsed 
       5.29    0.00    5.29 
    > system.time(replicate(10000, ddply( input , .(Product) , function(x) x[ - c( 1 : ceiling( nrow(x) * 0.25 ) ) , ] )))
      user  system elapsed 
      43.48    0.03   44.04 
    > system.time(replicate(10000,  DT[ ,  tail( .SD , -ceiling( nrow(.SD) * .25 ) )  , by = Product ] ))                        
      user  system elapsed 
      34.30    0.01   34.50
```

**BUT**: SimonO101's alternatives do *not* produce the same as `mapply`, becaused I used `mapply` using the `table_input` you posted; I don't know if this plays any role in the comparison. Also, the comparison may have been dumbly setted up by me. I just did it because of the speed issue you pointed. I'd, really, want @SimonO101 to see this in case I'm talking nonsense.

Comment: I don't think they are comparable - you get different (wrong according to OP) results. Also (and I don't know how this would affect timing) you should try it out on a low number of replications on a very large table, not many iterations on a small table (as that is what the OP problem stated - 2 million rows).

Comment: I tried your solution on a 2e6 row table and stopped it running after about 20 minutes. Try the two solutions using the data at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I, also, just tried my solution for a 2-million row dataframe and `R` was not responding for a fair amount of time. :). I guess `mapply` is out of the picture now.